# is it possible to have a successful handshake first and then purposely not send server certificate from server side?

Tags: android, ssl, https, certificate, handshake

is it possible to have a ServerHello first, so the client/server handshake is successful, and then make server purposely not send its CA certificate, so the client doesn't receive server certificate. Is there such a way/ a script to do it with mitmproxy?

Answer (score 1):

The TLS handshake is not done with the sending of ServerHello. The TLS handshake is only done with the sending of `Finished` by both peers. Authentication of the server is integral part of the TLS handshake.

It is not possible to successfully finish a TLS handshake where the used cipher requires a server certificate but then not send the certificate. It is possible though to use a cipher which does not require a server certificate in the first place. But these ciphers are not enabled by common client and server and when trying to enforce these ciphers in some man in the middle the handshake will fail due to no shared ciphers.